# Eland loading pandas dataframe to elasticsearch changes date

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, datetime, elasticsearch

Greetings Stackoverflowers

I have been using ([eland](https://www.swarmee.net/blog/2020-10-10-Loading-Data-Into-ElasticSearch-With-Python-Eland/) to insert a pandas dataframe as an elasticsearch document. The code used to make this happen is shown as follows and is strongly based on the one in the url

```
import eland as ed    
def save_to_elastic(data_df, elastic_engine, index_name, type_overrides_dict, chunk_size):
        """
            es_type_overrides={
                "fechaRegistro": "date",
                "fechaIncidente": "date"
            }
        """
        df = ed.pandas_to_eland(
            pd_df=data_df,
            es_client=elastic_engine,
            # Where the data will live in Elasticsearch
            es_dest_index=index_name,
            # Type overrides for certain columns, the default is keyword
            # name has been set to free text and year to a date field.
            es_type_overrides=type_overrides_dict,
            # If the index already exists replace it
            es_if_exists="replace",
            # Wait for data to be indexed before returning
            es_refresh=True,
            chunksize=chunk_size
    )
```

I have used to insert the pandas dataframe inside elasticsearch as follows:

```
from snippets.elastic_utils import save_to_elastic, conect2elastic
es = conect2elastic(user='falconiel')
save_to_elastic(data_df=siaf_consumados_elk,
                type_overrides_dict={'fechaRegistro':"date",
                                     'fechaIncidente':"date"}, 
                elastic_engine=es, 
                index_name='siaf_18032021_pc',
                chunk_size=1000)
```

Everything works fine but once I have the document in elasticsearch 26 dates have been inserted wrongly inside elasticsearch. **All my data starts in january 1 2015**. But elasticsearch shows **some documents with December 31 2014**. I haven't been able to find an explanation for this. Why some of the rows in the pandas dataframe that have the date field correct (from 2015-01-01) **were changed during loading** to last day of december of previous year. I would appreciate any help or insight to correct this behavior.

My datetime columns in pandas dataframe are typed as datetime. However, I am trying to test the following conversions to address the problem. They have not been so productive by now:

I have tried using the following conversions before inserting calling the function I use to save to the dataframe in elastic:

```
siaf_consumados_elk.fechaRegistro = pd.to_datetime(siaf_consumados_elk.fechaRegistro).dt.tz_localize(None)
siaf_consumados_elk.fechaRegistro = pd.to_datetime(siaf_consumados_elk.fechaRegistro, utc=True)
```

Comment: Elasticsearch assumes every timestamp it receives is in UTC. are you working in a different timezone in python?

Comment: That is a good question @MarkWalkom I don't know what UTC Python is working. The fact is that the columns in my pandas dataframe that have datetime data are formatted in  pandas as datetime. However, once the dataframe is written to elastic, 26 dates change from 2015-01-01 to 2014-12-31.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the problem is UTC. I checked some of the rows in the pandas dataframe and they were reduced almost one day. For instance, one record which was registered in 2021-01-02 GMT -5 appeared as 2021-01-01. The solution was to apply the corresponding time zone before calling the function to save the **dataframe** as an **elastic document/index**. So, considering the good observation given by Mark Walkom, this what I used before calling the function:

```
siaf_consumados_elk.fechaRegistro = siaf_consumados_elk.fechaRegistro.dt.tz_localize(tz='America/Guayaquil')
siaf_consumados_elk.fechaIncidente = siaf_consumados_elk.fechaIncidente.dt.tz_localize(tz='America/Guayaquil')
```

A list with the corresponding time zones can be found at: [python time zones](https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568)

This permitted to index the time corretly